# Systemd Unit service restart if another service start or reload

Tags: systemd

I'd like to know if there's a way with `Systemd` to restart `A.service` (`After`) when `B.service` get started or reloaded (reload config only), if possible without editing `B.service` which is installed and upgraded by the system.

`A.service` should start even if `B.service` is not installed, disabled or stopped.

`A.service`:

```
[Unit]
After = B.service network-online.target
Wants = B.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart = /script.sh start
ExecStop = /script.sh stop
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy = network-online.target
```

`B.service`:

```
[Unit]
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/cmd start
ExecStop=/cmd stop
ExecReload=/cmd reload
PIDFile=/var/run/cmd.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 29):

You can use `PartOf` in the `[Unit]` section.

Example: `PartOf=B.service`

From man page,

> PartOf=
>
> Configures dependencies similar to Requires=, but limited to stopping
>   and restarting of units. When systemd stops or restarts the units
>   listed here, the action is propagated to this unit. Note that this is
>   a one-way dependency — changes to this unit do not affect the listed
>   units.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking into `Overriding vendor settings` but this looks even more easy and promising, only excpetion is I don't want `A` to stop if `B` stop, just `A.restart` if `B.start`, anyway I'll do some test soon and see if there's some way to manage it, then will let you know

Comment: @Alex : What if you use `PartOf` and `Restart=always` together?

Comment: I'm looking at `Restart=` documentation, I'm not sure what is the behavior with `oneshot` services, but regardless: `When the death of the process is a result of systemd operation (e.g. service stop or restart), the service will not be restarted`, if I understand correctly manually stopping B would stop A

Comment: Well now, the bounty auto-assigned itself for expiration, @Thushi I appreciate your effort and the suggestion but `PartOf` is not a solution for the question, enjoy anyway.

Comment: @Alex: Well, Points are not important to me. There are so many other ways I can earn points. I just want to know whether the provided solution solves your issue. If not, we will work on it further. How about using `PartOf` with `Restart=always`? Did you tried that?

Comment: I was just observing how dump is the assignment of the expirated bounty, again, really appreciate your effort. I haven't tried `Restart=` because the one I'm currently using seems to work and the only side effect could be a double start fof A at reboot (haven't checked yet)

Comment: Anyway I'll take some time in the next days to give `Restart=` a try and then will let you know

Answer (score 4):

I had no control over `stop` with `PartOf=`, and `A` must not stop with `B`, so I ended up using *Overriding vendor settings*, seems to work.

`/etc/systemd/system/B.service.d/override.conf`

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/cmd start || exit $?; sleep 5; [ -x /script.sh ] && /script.sh start; exit 0'
ExecReload=
ExecReload=/bin/sh -c '/cmd reload || exit $?; sleep 5; [ -x /script.sh ] && /script.sh start; exit 0'
```

`/cmd` implementation is asynchronous and access a resource which `/script.sh` need to access too, I found nothing better (for now) to sleep few seconds.

I tried to use `systemctl [--no-block] try-restart` before using `/script.sh` directly but didn't work.

Comment: I am also looking for a solution for this scenario. Could you please explain this solution a bit more? or give a link to some docs to read and understand what you have done.

Comment: Hi @zappy, look for the manual `man systemd.unit` (or search it online if isn't installed) and look for for the "Overriding vendor settings" chapter.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I understand that you choose the above method only because service B is a vendor specific and you dont want to edit that service file.  But in my case both service A and B are not vendor delivered. I feel overriding it may add complexity to the system. Do we have any other options ?

Comment: The question is a couple of years old, did you check the documentation? Maybe this scenario has been covered since. At the time I was in a hurry but having time I would look for the [systemd official mailing](https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel) list and ask there, eventually open an issue

Answer (score 3):

At the moment systemd doesn't cover this senario. You can't achieve this functionality through service files alone. One possibility is to hijack systemctl via a shell script with the same name and in that check to see if B.service is about to be re/started or reloaded, do the appropriate action with A.service as well, and if needed update the rc.local to get to the proper state at boot as well. I have this problem with docker.service and networking.service, but I just always restart them together:

> systemctl restart docker.service networking.service

Obviously, this would not be effective if systemd itself manipulate B.service internally ( e.g. via other service files.).